# Inline Attachment image is not displaying in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, email, inline, attachment

I've been trying to show inline attachments in my mail (logo),
I've seen many answers on the community, nothing seems to be working for me,
Mail is going fine,I can see the text but unable to see image

this is my mailer:
path variable contains path to logo

```
attachments.inline['logo.png'] = { content: File.read(path),mime_type: "image/png" }
```

this is my view:
Welcome to my site

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url%>
```

Please Help,I've been pulling my hair for hours now on this.

Comment: hey Rajesh, ever find a solution

Answer (score 1):

In your mailer try:

```
attachments.inline["myimage.png"] = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "app", "assets", "images", "myimage.png"))
```

your view code is correct.

I've been using this code successfully with one image, though there may be a bug in rails. Check: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2686